# How do I verify that all my assets are precompiled

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I recently ran into this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (costa rica.png isn't precompiled):
```

Now I know how to fix this particular issue (and others like it), but it's sort of a pain to have to track them down one at a time.

Ideally, there would be some sort of way I could check all my *_tag in my views, compare them to the results of my pre-compilation and run this as a build task.

What I'm asking: is there a way in rails to do this already, or should I be writing my own Rake task?

Answer (score 0):

Rails' asset pipeline pre-compiles all non-JS/CSS assets in the `app/assets/`, `lib/assets/` and `vendor/assets/` folders by default. Which folders do your errant files reside in?

If these files are elsewhere consider either re-organizing them into the one of the above folders (recommended), or adding `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('path', 'to', 'assets')` in your `application.rb` file.

Details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question.  I want to know if I'm going to render anything that's not included.  A sanity check.